# How do I configure Alpine to use Azure Active Directory as a Directory?

Tags: alpine-mail

I would like to use my company's Azure Active Directory to look up email addresses when composing messages in Alpine. However, I did not find any instructions on how to configure these settings:

```
ldap-server          = <No Value Set>                                                                                               
search-base          = <No Value Set>                                                                                               
port                 = <No Value Set: using "389">                                                                                  
bind-dn              = <No Value Set>                                                                                               
nickname             = <No Value Set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD is an entirely different technology from traditional AD and doesn't have native LDAP support by default. To get full LDAP support, the company needs to set up "Azure AD DS" – which is basically a cloud-hosted traditional AD domain controller that synchronizes with Azure AD.

In other words, there are no standard instructions; it's up to your company whether AD DS is made available. For the curious, the Azure *administrator* instructions seem to be at:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-ldap
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-instance
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-configure-ldaps

Also, even *if* AD DS is available, your company's Azure admins also need to actually add the LDAP server to DNS and configure a TLS certificate for LDAPS.

**Generic instructions for readers who know they have LDAP but don't know where**

It might be worth trying `ldap.yourdomain.com` or `ldap.ad.yourdomain.com` (using LDAPS on port 636) – not through Alpine just yet, but first using the `ldapsearch` CLI tool. At the same time, this will help you determine the host name and the *search-base* parameter:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.example.com -x -s base -b "" namingContexts
```

If you do find the LDAP server in this way, doing a search with these specific parameters will show its rootDSE which contains the correct "search base" in the `namingContexts` field. (In this example it is very likely to be "dc=example,dc=com".)

The *port* is 636 for LDAPS ('require-ldaps' in Alpine) and 389 for StartTLS ('require-tls') as well as plaintext LDAP. You should always enable one of these two TLS modes, as Alpine doesn't support the Kerberos authentication that AD would prefer.

The *bind-dn* field is the LDAP account name. AD DS supports specifying the Active Directory UPN (e.g. "user@ad.example.com") in this field, which is convenient although non-standard.

The *nickname* is just how Alpine will label this address book in its UI.